# Auto Scroll to Div Override

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list of links the href if each link is a div on the current page so that I can change the div display setting when clicked with some javascript. The current annoying issue is when you click on a link it scrolls to the div location. I don't want it to scroll to the div I just need to show it.

Links in list

```
<li><a href="#victimcenterdiv" class="side-a-li">THE CRIME
                        VICTIMS CENTER</a></li>
                <li><a href="#victimrightsdiv" class="side-a-li">CRIME
                        VICTIM LEGAL RIGHTS</a></li>
```

div and css

```
<div id="victimcenterdiv" class="ui-div-interface ui-show">
            <span>12345</span>
        </div>


.ui-div-interface {
    background: none;
    top: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 9%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}

.ui-show {
    display: block !important;
}
```

finally the javascript/jquery responsible:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').not($('#search-reg-options')).click(function() {
            $('.ui-show').removeClass('ui-show')
            var mydiv = $(this).attr('href');
            $(mydiv).addClass('ui-show');
        });

        $('#search-reg-options').click(function() {
            $('.options-shown').removeClass('options-shown')
            var mydiv = $(this).attr('href');
            $(mydiv).addClass('options-shown');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**QUESTION** How do I stop the auto scroll that happens when someone clicks the links that I have in my list?

Comment: So you effectively want the links to do nothing?

Comment: No it will show the div and change display: none; into display: block !important; but doesn't scroll the screen so that it is in view

Comment: You shouldn't use the `href="#victimcenterdiv"` attribute of the `a` tag. If you are using HTML5, it is not required.

Comment: You can leave the href in if you use preventDefault(), however both ways are a valid way of doing what you are attempting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your view automatically scrolls is because your `a` is anchored to the `div` with an `id` of `victimcenterdiv`, since you have the attribute `href="#victimcenterdiv"`.

You can simply change the attribute to `href="#"`. Alternatively, you can just remove the `href` attribute altogether in HTML5.

However, your jquery code currently depends on the href. So that means you will have to add a different attribute to help your code differentiate which `div` to make visible. One way you could do this is with the [`data-*` attributes.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) This allows you to embed custom attributes with custom values to your `a` tag.

```
<a data-display="#victimcenterdiv" class="side-a-li">
```

To get the value of the `data` attribute in jquery, use the [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) method.

```
var mydiv = $(this).data('display');
$(mydiv).addClass('ui-show');
```

Comment: If I remove the href attr how does the javascript tell which div to set to visible?

Comment: @YaWang You can use the `data-*` attribute instead. I will update my answer shortly to explain.

Comment: Additionally using this method will likely cause you to want to add CSS such as .side-a-li { cursor:pointer; } to maintain the view that the link is clickable. Anchor tags without a href attribute lose the default cursor attributes. Not sure if that applies in all browsers, but that has been my experience in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) method. This tells the event to stop whatever default behavior the element had, and continue with only the script you have following the `.preventDefault()`.

```
$('a').not($('#search-reg-options')).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.ui-show').removeClass('ui-show')
    var mydiv = $(this).attr('href');
    $(mydiv).addClass('ui-show');
});

$('#search-reg-options').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.options-shown').removeClass('options-shown')
    var mydiv = $(this).attr('href');
    $(mydiv).addClass('options-shown');
});
```

Comment: Yours worked but I want to see what the other kid has to say about html5, I am gonna give you an up for points for now :D

Comment: His method will work as well. Both are valid ways, just different approaches.